# How to access a post author's profile picture in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, image

I am trying to display a username's profile picture in a blog/social media app when some user clicks on some other user's username but it is currently not working.

In my template: (I think my issue is I don't have access to post?)

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <article class="media content-section">
        <img class="img-thumbnail account-img mt-3 " src="{{ username.profile.image.url }}">
    </article>

    <h1 class="mb-3">Posts by {{ view.kwargs.username }} ({{ page_obj.paginator.count }})</h1>

<div class="infinite-container">
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="infinite-item">
            <article class="media content-section">
              <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
    <!--            profile (model in user ).image (attribute) -->
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                  <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
              </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My users\models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

In my blog/models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I can retrieve some user's username by `{{ view.kwargs.username }}`, how can I do this with profile pictures?

my blog\views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Post #from the model file in the current package import the Post class
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)


def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all(), # querying the database
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5


class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        # it will get that user form that database if it exist, if user doesn't exist return 404,
        # we are also using the User model, so need to import it
        # 2nd parameter means that we are getting the username from the url
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        # showing the posts by that specific user only
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')

# Looking at individual post
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})


def search(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        posts = Post.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=searched) |
            Q(author__username__icontains=searched))

        usernames = []
        for post in posts:
            usernames.append(post.author)
        # remove duplicates of username
        usernames = list(set(usernames))

        context = {'searched': searched, 'posts': posts, 'usernames': usernames}
        return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/search.html', {})
```

Comment: Please show the view that renders this template, is `post` present in the context passed to the template?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have included a portion of my views.py, I have other classes in my views however

Comment: @Jarad it is in home view. don't you see?

Comment: @Jarad it is in my blog\views.py. Do you know how I should fix this? I can access the the post author's profile picture, but I need to call for post in posts first. But I don't need to loop it?

Comment: @Jarad Hi Jarad, thank you for the thoughtful comments. Sorry I know my question isn't clear as I am very new to django. Yes I am looping through ```posts``` to get my ```post``` object. I have included my full code this time. Thank you.

Comment: @Jarad Thanks for the help, I am not sure what by creating the profile for the user, I don't have a specific view for profile. Should I create this? I am a bit confused when should I need to write a view. And yes I can confirm that images are being uploaded in my media directory

Comment: @Jarad I want to display the user's profile and user's posts (UserPostListView(ListView)), together. post.author.profile.image.url works but I have to loop through posts first. Yes, I have already set up the media files in settings

Comment: @Jarad I got ``` <img class="img-thumbnail account-img mt-3 " src="">.```  No src. But profile picture is displayed when I called ```{{post.author.profile.image.url }} ``` after I called for post in posts. ``` <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="/media/default.jpg">```

Comment: @Jarad Yes for everything. I have done all of those as I followed a youtube tutorial series. It is only now that I am on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ForeignKey` instead of `OneToOneField`. Add a `related_name`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
```

in html:

```
<img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
```

---

**You can write a custom method also.**

e.g:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ...

    def get_owner_pp(self):
        return self.author.profile.image.url
```

in html:

```
<img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.get_owner_pp }}">
```